# Convert value from HTML input tag as a string in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to get the value from this HTML input tag :

```
<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="typeahead" />
</form>
```

and `SpellCorrector::correct` function in the following PHP get the value as a string, because it's only accept value from a string type :

```
<?php
$box = $_POST("search");
include 'SpellCorrector.php';
$correct = SpellCorrector::correct($box);
echo $correct;
?>
```

The code above isn't working, so I guess I should find a way to convert the `$box` variable into string type but I don't know how to. Or maybe there's a better solution for my problem.

I'm using [this](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4859-PHP-Suggest-corrected-spelling-text-in-pure-PHP.html) for SpellCorrector.php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the PHP part of the code. `$_POST` returns array and you should access it that way. Use `$box = $_POST["search"]` instead.

```
<?php
    $box = $_POST["search"];
    include 'SpellCorrector.php';
    $correct = SpellCorrector::correct($box);
    echo $correct;
?>
```

Comment: Same method as above, not working. `Undefined index: search` comes out

Comment: How are you submitting the form? You are missing submit button in the HTML snippet you shared. 

`<form name="form" action="" method="post">
<input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="typeahead" />
<input type='submit' value="Send" name="submit" />
</form>`

Then, since the action attribute is "" I assume you are handling them in the same .php file. You should check if `isset($_POST['submit'])` before trying to get the `$_POST['search']`

Comment: Copy paste the whole file so I would be able to assist further

Comment: now I know operator `isset` is really useful, anyway, can I submit the form without using the submit button? thanks @ToshoTrajanov

Comment: Glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

You need Square brackets. []

```
<?php
$box = $_POST["search"];
include 'SpellCorrector.php';
$correct = SpellCorrector::correct($box);
echo $correct;
?>
```

Comment: It turns out to be `Undefined index : search`